# Erro no wamp via redelocal

Tags: aplicação-web, apache, servidor, virtualhost, host

Boa noite.

Eu instalei um sisteminha web em uma maquina onde tenho instalado o Wamp 3.1.0, mas quando vou tentar acessa-lo através de outra maquina conectada na mesma rede eu me deparo com o seguinte erro:

"Forbidden. You dont have permission to acess /on this server. ------ Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31 Server at *.**.**.** Port 80"

Encontrei alguns tutoriais alterações no arquivo httpd.config, no apache. No alias, em PHPMyAdmin, porem nenhum deu certo, alguns inclusive impedem os serviços wamp de serem executados. Acredito que os tutoriais que eu achei sejam para versões anteriores do Wamp.

Ps. ja desativei o firewall, e não resolveu.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Demérito por ''nenhum esforço de pesquisa''? Podem me banir pelo comentário se quiserem, mas para mim a pessoa que opnou isso é louco, ou muito sem noção. Pois literalmente não tem noção da quantidade de fóruns e tutoriais que eu segui sem sucesso antes de postar a duvida aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o intuito de ajudar outros desenvolvedores que enfrentem o mesmo problema, eis aqui a resposta:

no arquivo "..\wamp\bin\apache\apache****\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf"

encontre o trecho de codigo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

na linha "Require local" por "Require all granted", ou caso queira ser mais especifico, por:

```
Require local

Require ip 192.168.1.100
Require ip 192.168.1.101
```

(trocando os IPs acima pelos IPs que acessarão a aplicação)

PS. Este é o procedimento correto para as versões 3.x do Wamp.